# How to load Ratings Image in Datalist in Asp.net {Object reference not set to an instance of an object}

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
public void Ratings()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Ratings From tbl_Movies Where MovieId='"+movie_id+"'",con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
   c= dr["Ratings"].ToString();
   count = Convert.ToDouble(c);
    dr.Close();
   if (count == 1.0)
    {
        DataList item =new DataList();
       Image l = (Image)item.FindControl("Image3") as Image;
       l.ImageUrl=("~/Images/cal.gif"); `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, this line:

```
 Image l = (Image)item.FindControl("Image3") as Image;
```

Did not find the image, because you are creating a new datalist:

```
DataList item =new DataList();
```

Instead of getting the one on the ASP.NET page:

```
DataList item = datalistIDonPage;
```